# Weird regular expression output

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this code:

```
echo preg_match ("%^[A-Za-z0-9]$%", stripslashes(trim(X)));
```

for `X = "peter"` the output is: 0

for `X = "peter."` the output is also 0

but when I remove `^`, it suddenly starts to work:

```
echo preg_match ("%[A-Za-z0-9]$%", stripslashes(trim(X)));
```

for `X = "peter"` it returns 1 and for `"peter."` it returns 0.
Is it correct to use it without `^`? It's weird.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your charclass only matches one character. It has no quantifier `*`/`+` attached .

Comment: Oh, that was simple solution. Thanks
"echo preg_match ("%[A-Za-z0-9]+$%", stripslashes(trim(X)));"

Answer (score 1):

You need to match multiple characters using the `*` character:

```
echo preg_match ("%^[A-Za-z0-9]*$%", stripslashes(trim(X)));
```

Or use the `+` modifier

```
echo preg_match ("%^[A-Za-z0-9]+$%", stripslashes(trim(X)));
```

to only match strings with `length() > 0`.

Comment: This will even match empty string

Comment: @HamZa Sure. Did jevniky stated, that he didn't want to match the empty string?

Comment: I don't want to match empty string. :) sorry for not saying it before. I'm using it to check username. And similar ones for email, etc.